# From a list of companies, stream tweets into df's?

Tags: r, list, loops, for-loop, tweetr

From a txt document I will have a list of companies, say Telstra, Optus and Samsung.

After importing this list into R, I need a loop that will do the equivalent of the code below. The list could be any number of companies so my main issue here is that it needs to be automated.

```
df1 <- search_tweets2("Telstra", retryonratelimit = TRUE,include_rts=FALSE)
df2 <- search_tweets2("Optus", retryonratelimit = TRUE,include_rts=FALSE)
df3 <- search_tweets2("Samsung", retryonratelimit = TRUE,include_rts=FALSE)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may use `lapply` or purrr's `map` functions to loop through each company name. If there are lot of companies to search for use `Sys.sleep` to avoid hitting the limit.

```
df <- data.frame(companies = c("Telstra", "Optus", "Samsung"))

result <- purrr::map_df(df$companies, ~{
  search_tweets2(.x, retryonratelimit = TRUE,include_rts=FALSE)
  #Sys.sleep(5)
}, .id = 'id')
```

Comment: Hey Ronak, it's coming up with "Error in vector("list", ntimes) : invalid 'length' argument". Do you know why this could be?

Comment: That is strange. Not sure what might be causing it. Did you try restarting R/RStudio and trying again?

Comment: It was my firewall!!